# Copy a Visual Studio Project removing git source

Tags: git, visual-studio

this is my problem.
I have a project in visual studio linked to a remote repository on bitbucket and I'm working on it with other people.
I'd like to make a copy of this project to work on it alone and I want that changes I make on this copy do NOT apply on the original project.
I want the new copy have another project name and to NOT be linket to that remote repository.
I tried with File -> Save as, but when i work on it, it still is linked to the repo and when I enter the directory in which it is I don't see any .git files to remove to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps that you need to follow:

1. Create a remote repository on Bitbucket.
   Add that repository host in your existing local repository:

   ```
   `git remote add new-origin remote_repository_url`
   ```
2. Check if it is added or not. Below given command will list all the remotes associated with this repository:

   ```
   `git remote -v`
   ```
3. Now (if required) you can remove your previous remote repository host by following command:

   ```
   `git remote remove origin`
   ```
4. That's all. Now you can push any of your branch to your new repository by:
       `git push new-origin branch_name`

And believe me, removing `.git` directory is not a solution as you will loose all your version history. ;)

Comment: So, if I understood well.. I copy my project and I link an empty repo to my new copy so that it doesn't interfere with the repo of the original project?
And another question... if the two projects have the same names (and the same namespaces) are they different projectos for Visual Studio?

Comment: You don't need to copy it. You need to perform the above mentioned steps with in your existing project folder. You just need to create a blank repository on bitbucket.

Comment: But I need a copy of the project to work on it! 
I have Project A that works and it's fine. I need Project B to be the copy of A but to be independent from it

Comment: Maybe I just explained myself the wrong way.
I have a Xamarin.Forms project (I work on Visual Studio 2015 Community) linked to a Bitbucket repository.
I want to make a copy of this project with a new name (and a new workspace folder) and be sure that the two projects are completely differente projects with no links between them and that I can work separately on them . Obviously the new project does NOT have to be linked to the Bitbucket repository of the first one.
Does the function "Save as" of visual studio ensures me this?

Comment: I see. If you want them to be in isolation,  You have to simply copy paste the entire folder and perform the above steps on the newly pasted folder.

Comment: And for rename the copy I have to manually change file, workspace, ecc?